# Submit should run action not jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I have this script which checks if the textbox input is an URL.

If the input is correct then it should perform the action.

Problem is, right now the button doesn't run the action, it just checks if the textbox is a valid URL, and I don't really understand the code properly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});;
</script>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});

$("#field").keyup(function(){
$('#myform').valid();
});
  });
  </script>



<form id="myform" action="http://google.com">
  <label for="field">Required, URL: </label>
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "perform the action"? Submit the form? -- So, problem is that when you click the "Go" button form doesn't get submitted..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fiddling with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ7Fh/14/ I found out that it seems to be the `debug: true` that, for some reason, is preventing the normal form execution. Just comment out that line, and it works as it should..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/S4WdN/1/

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        }
    });

    $("#field").keyup(function(){
        $('#myform').valid();
    });

    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to add a SUBMIT event listener to the form. In this case, I'm stopping the form from submitting the form altogether. If, and only if, the form validates, the user will be redirected to the address entered.

Comment: Thanks Ayman, but I need it to run the action rather than the URL. This is because the action is important in my particular code. So basically I only need jquery for telling the user about invalid URL's other than that it's a normal form.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I've edited my answer to submit the form instead.

Comment: @AymanSafadi what jquery.validate does is to require validation before normal execution, so there's no need to check whether form `.isvalid()` with a custom submit handler function..